# Convert String of Hex and Ints to List in Python

Tags: string, hex, python-2.7

I'm trying to find the maximum value in a string of hex numbers. My approach is to convert is to tokenize the string, convert that list of tokens into ints and then take the max value.

The string is formatted like so:

```
'\x1e\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x0f184203308373388492761797873987'
```

I cannot control the format because it is the output of the Python binding of the LZ4 algorithm.

Other similar answers on SO don't have mixed types or use escape characters in a string with many hex numbers.

So, how do I turn that into a list such as:

```
[0x1e, 0x00, 0x00, ...]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you referring to the output of `lz4.compress()`?  If so, the string isn't a list of hex numbers.  `lz4.compress("z"*10) == '\n\x00\x00\x00\xa0zzzzzzzzzz'`, for example.

Comment: @DSM I was referring to the output of lz4.dumps(). But, the output looks similar, except the ending is integers in my example.  What are the parts of your string after '\x'?

Comment: The same thing holds: consider `lz4.dumps("z"*10) == '\n\x00\x00\x00\xa0zzzzzzzzzz'`.  I agree that the two digits after the "x" are hexadecimal, but which characters get them and which don't is a fluke of encoding.  Look at `lz4.dumps("\xff"*10)`, for example.  Are you simply after max(ord(x) for x in s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how do you want to get the take the integers after the hex value ... Are they supposed to be 1, 2, or *x* digits ?

So, I do this:

```
import re

# convert unicode or string to raw
def raw(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        s = s.encode('string-escape')
    elif isinstance(s, unicode):
        s = s.encode('unicode-escape')
    return s

s = '\x1e\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x0f184203308373388492761797873987'

print [ re.sub(r'\\', r'0', raw(i)) for i in s]
```

And I get this:

```
['0x1e', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0xf0', '0x0f', '1', '8', '4', '2', '0', '3', '3', '0', '8', '3', '7', '3', '3', '8', '8', '4', '9', '2', '7', '6', '1', '7', '9', '7', '8', '7', '3', '9', '8', '7']
```

Hope that could help

**edit:** simplified the list comprehension

**edit:** if you indeed want to get rid of non hex values, then you could use

```
>>> print [int(re.sub(r'\\', r'0', raw(i)), 16) for i in s if len(raw(i))>1]
[30, 0, 0, 0, 240, 15]
```

and comparing ... or even way better, as [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) stated

```
>>> s = '\x1e\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x0f184203308373388492761797873987'
>>> ord(max(s))
240
```

Comment: Geez. I was complicating something simple. My thanks to both you and @DSM